# How do I specify a CMake include path that works natively, and in Yocto?

Tags: c++, cmake, yocto, yocto-recipe

I'm working on a C++ application that reads image data from an [Optris thermal camera](https://www.optris.co.uk/xi-410). To talk to the camera, I'm using the [Direct SDK](https://www.optris.global/sdk), which can be downloaded [here](https://evocortex.org/downloads/). I use CMake to build my application on my Linux development machine, and it all seems to work well.

The SDK consists of a `.deb` file, and it basically just installs some libraries into `/usr/lib`, and some header files into `/usr/include/libirimager`.

I'm now trying to build this same application into my Yocto image, for an Nvidia Jetson board. However, I'm not able to `#include` the SDK header files, because my `CMakeLists.txt` file specifies an absolute path for the libirimager header files.

I've stripped my code down to the very minimum needed to reproduce the problem.

main.cpp:

```cpp
#include "IRImager.h"

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(libir-example)

add_executable(libir-example
    main.cpp
)

target_include_directories(libir-example PRIVATE
    /usr/include/libirimager
)

target_link_libraries(libir-example PUBLIC
    irdirectsdk
)
```

The above builds correctly on my Linux machine.

I made an example yocto recipe that just tries to compile `main.cpp` using the CMake file.

libir-example.bb:

```
DESCRIPTION = "Example of trying to build for libir"
LICENSE = "BSD"

SRCREV = "0.1"
PV = "0.1"
SRC_URI = "file://main.cpp file://CMakeLists.txt"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

DEPENDS += "optris-directsdk"

deltask do_populate_lic

inherit cmake
```

Running `bitbake libir-example` gets as far as trying to compile it, but then fails with:

```
| /home/foo/build/tmp/work/armv8a-oe4t-linux/libir-example/0.1-r0/main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: IRImager.h: No such file or directory
|     1 | #include "IRImager.h"
|       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The file mentioned has definitely been copied into my `recipe-sysroot`:

```
-rw-r--r-- 5 foo foo 27565 Apr  7  2022 recipe-sysroot/usr/include/libirimager/IRImager.h
```

I'm fairly sure it is because I have an absolute path in my `CMakeLists.txt` file, but I'm not sure what I should use instead.

I tried changing my include directive to this:

```
target_include_directories(libir-example PRIVATE
    ${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/usr/include/libirimager
)
```

but this had no effect. (The `-I` passed to `g++` is unchanged.) I also tried this:

```
target_include_directories(libir-example PRIVATE
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/../recipe-sysroot/usr/include/libirimager
)
```

This works, but is very ugly, and more importantly, means I can't build natively any more.

I'm sure there is a very simple solution that eludes me.

EDIT: Here's the `optris-directsdk` recipe I made to install the SDK into the sysroot:

optris-directsdk_8.8.5.bb:

```
SUMMARY = "Optris DirestSDK"
DESCRIPTION = "SDK for talking to Optris thermal cameras"
HOMEPAGE = "https://www.optris.co.uk/optris-pi-sdks"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

inherit bin_package

SRC_URI += " \
    https://ftp.evocortex.org/libirimager-latest?arch=arm64&type=deb;subdir=optris-directsdk-8.8.5;downloadfilename=libirimager-8.8.5.deb \
"

SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "97661cd4c258c1dde55938b7d18d7be5fa9a1480e0f0b0bb96268ad62089905f"

# Force the .so files into the regular package (not the -dev one)
FILES:${PN} += "/usr/lib/lib*.so"
FILES:${PN}-dev = ""

RDEPENDS:${PN} = "libudev libusb1"

# Need this because the libraries in the SDK are already stripped, which
# bitbake does not expect

INSANE_SKIP:${PN} = "already-stripped"

# Remove the parts of the SDK that we don't need (e.g. udev rules), otherwise
# bitbake complains about things existing that are not installed.

do_install:append() {
    rm -rf ${D}/lib
    rm -rf ${D}/usr/lib/libirextras.so
}
```

Comment: Hello, your CMakeLists specifies an absolute path for the libirimager header files, this is your key problem here. When you depends on something out of your project, you should use 'find_library' cmake command to search for your needed files (lib & headers) and create a cmake target to link with. Using Yocto is really the same logic, you can have a recipe `irimager_%.bb` which retrieve the libirimager and then, another recipe `ir-example_%.bb' with a dependency relationship using the DEPENDS keyword in your recipe.

Comment: Thank you @Martin. I couldn't make it work with `find_library()`, but I've got a workaround using `find_path(IRPATH NAMES libirimager/IRImager.h REQUIRED)`. I don't know if there is a more canonical answer, but this works so is good enough for now.

Comment: Does your toolchain file contain [`set(CMAKE_SYSROOT "/.../recipe-sysroot")`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SYSROOT.html)? (I assume you're cross-compiling)

Comment: @fabian Yes, I'm cross-compiling for ARM `aarch64`. It does seem the build system (bitbake) has created a `toolchain.cmake` file, but it does not contain any occurrence of `CMAKE_SYSROOT`.

Comment: You use `DEPENDS += "optris-directsdk"` in your recipe. Where does it come from? Did you write a recipe for `optris-directsdk` yourself?

Comment: @JonasVautherin Yes, this is another recipe I made that just installs the SDK into the sysroot. I'll add it to the question. It seems to work, all the things from the SDK appear in the correct place.

Comment: Hmm I am not sure if Yocto sets any CMake variable at build time that would say where the rootfs is. I think I would write a pkg-config file for optris-directsdk (a `.pc` file, that's pretty easy) and have the optris-directsdk recipe install it. Then I would have CMake find directsdk with pkg-config. That's anyway cleaner than hardcoding the paths.

Comment: Thanks @JonasVautherin, I'll maybe look into that tomorrow! I do have a workaround that works (a `find_path()`) and we're trying to finish this part of the project by the end of the month, but I'll do my best to investigate this option.

Comment: If you go with `find_path()`, a clean alternative is to write a cmake module (i.e. your own FindDirectSDK.cmake in your example project). That way you can put all your `find_path()` logic inside that file (at first hardcoding everything you want) but still use `find_package` in the CMakeLists.txt. Later you can improve the module file (or not), but at least you did not pollute your CMakeLists :).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [GNUInstallDirs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GNUInstallDirs.html), e.g.:

```
include(GNUInstallDirs)

...

target_include_directories(libir-example PRIVATE
    "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/libirimager>"
    "$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/libirimager>"
)
```

or simply:

```
include(GNUInstallDirs)

...

target_include_directories(libir-example PRIVATE
    "${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/libirimager"
)
```